# Need a linq query where inclusion indicates property matches all values in secondary list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I want to duplicate the following logic in a single query.

```
var currentRows = resultsTable.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var wholeWord in excludeWholeWords)
{
    currentRows = from row in currentRows
        where !FoundWholeWord(wholeWord, row.Field<string>("busdescl"))
        select row;

}
resultsTable = currentRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

I had tried the following, but it results in matching if !FoundWholeWord is true for any wholeWord, instead of my intent (which is that a match means !FoundWholeWord is true for ALL items in excludeWholeWords

```
var matchGvRows = (from wholeWord in excludeWholeWords
  from row in gvkeysTable.AsEnumerable()
  where !FoundWholeWord(wholeWord, row.Field<string>("busdescl"))
  select row).Distinct();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it should be something along the lines of:

```
var newRows = currentRows
  .Where(r => !excludeWholeWords.Any(w => w == r.Field<string>("busdescl"));
```

I don't know what the `FoundWholeWord` is but if it does anything different than just comparing strings, you can use it like:

```
var newRows = currentRows
  .Where(r => !excludeWholeWords.Any(w => FoundWholeWord(w, r.Field<string>("busdescl")));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var matchGvRows = excludeWholeWords.Aggregate(currentRows, (current, wholeWord) => current.Where(row => !FoundWholeWord(wholeWord, row.Field<string>("busdescl"))));
```

Comment: Aggregate works as I intended, but takes quite a bit longer than the second example from @Klaus.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentRows = excludeWholeWords.Aggregate(currentRows, (current, wholeWord) => (from row in current
                                                                                        where !FoundWholeWord(wholeWord, row.Field<string>("busdescl"))
                                                                                        select row));
```

That's what ReSharper's "Convert to LINQ expression" does.